# VLOOKUP together with MATCH

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-match

I have the below lookup condition but can't seem to get it working.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Raw Data'!A1:A3,MATCH('Submitted Data'!B1,'Submitted Data'!A1:B1))
```

I'm trying to pull in the B column value from `Submitted Data` into the B column in `Raw Data` based of a match on A columns, I just keep getting an error.

**Raw Data**

```
     A      B      C
1   L1             23
2   L2             17
3   L7             31
```

**Submitted Data**

```
     A      B
1   L1      Complete
2   L7      Pending
3   L2      Complete
```

Comment: Try `=VLOOKUP(A1, 'Submitted Data'!A1:B3,2,FALSE)`, as you're looking up the value in A1, and pulling the data from Submitted data, and you're returning the 2nd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vlookup` does the `match` for you so you don't need that function. This should work for you:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, 'Submitted Data'!A1:B3,2,FALSE)
```

Where

`A1` is the cell with the value you want to find in a different range of cells (i.e, the data on the other sheet.

`Submitted Data'!A1:B3` is the range of cells containing the data you want to find your `A1` in, and then return the value that's a defined number of columns away from it (see the next sentence).

`2` is the column from the range `Submitted Data'!A1:B3` (i.e. column `B`) that has the value you want to return.

`FALSE` means you want an exact match for your `A1` value.