# Excel : Value Sheet 1 (Find at Sheet 2) Copy the Value next to the cell

Tags: excel, vba

Anyone can help me on VBA or Excel commands.
I have 10,000 of data which have an ID and Value.

I have 2 Sheet of Data.

1. First Sheet: ID and Value but unordered.
2. Second Sheet : Control Sheet have ID and Data.

I want to ask how can I copy the ID at first sheet and find the same ID at second sheet and copy the value (let's say next to the copied cell) and paste at the second sheet next to the same ID.

Comment: If you really need VBA code, try something first, when you get stuck edit your question and add relevant code. If not, this is [`Vlookup`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) as what tospig posted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430090/vlookup-together-with-match/28430648#28430648) where it sounds like you can use a standard `vlookup` formula.

Assuming the `id` values are in `Column A` on both sheets, and the `values` are in `Column B` on both sheets, in `Column C` of the second sheet use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```